# Expected value and variance of random variable on some terms(dates?)

Tags: probability, generating-functions, random, variance

I have a exercise that sounds like this:
Find the expected value and the variance of the random variable X with natural values in terms of:

a)generating function P

b)generating function Q

Excercise is translated from polish in orginal it sound like this:

"Wyznacz wartość oczekiwaną oraz wariancję zmiennej losowej X o wartościach naturalnych
w terminach:
a)funkcji tworzącej P
b)funkcji tworzącej Q"

Where $$
P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_nx^n
$$
$$
p_n=P(X=n)
$$
$$
Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty q_nx^n
$$
$$
q_n=P(X>n)
$$

I have two question to this what thas it mean to find some values on terms and how should i start with this kind of exercises?

Comment: What do you mean "natural values on dates?" Was this question translated.

Comment: its sound that i need to find EX and VarX where X is random variable w natural values, then it says to make it in terms (in orginal in polish "terminach") generating function P and generating function Q

Comment: But by natural values on dates, do you mean, say, like 5 March or 8 December?

Comment: No naural values in mean natural numbers and there is one word that i dont know how to translate to english that normally woud be translated as dates or terms and that word is "terminy" its says to find EX and VarX in terms of P and Q and X is natural number